# How do send raw put data with request npm in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, npm, put

I need to hit an api using "require" npm in node. The api requires raw put data (not put fields).
How do I do this using request npm?

example raw put data I need to send:

```
var body = {
   "id": 123,
   "squares": [
       {
           square_id: 345,
           color: "#ccc"
       },
       {
           square_id: 777,
           color: "#fff"
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
        request({
            method: "PUT",
            uri: UPDATE_GAME,
            multipart: [{
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you dig into the code, you'll see that for the most basic of POST/PUT operations you can use the json options parameter.  It will also do the JSON.stringify() for you - your code becomes simply:

```
request({
  method: "PUT",
  uri: UPDATE_GAME,
  json: body
 });
```

Comment: How to get the body ,response and error from the put call after it gets executed ? @Michael Angstadt

Comment: You can pass a 2nd param of a callback matching cb = function(err, response, body){} so something like request(opts, cb)

Comment: @Michael Angstadt there are difference in PUT and PATCH request,

PUT: take whole object in the body and update all fields.

PATCH: take only that properties which you want updates, in that case whole object of json no need to send in patch request.

how do we send data into patch request?

Answer (score 1):

`body` is a JavaScript object. You are claiming to be sending JSON.

Pass it through [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Right, I made a mistake when munging the code to post it here. It does stringify the json. Fixed the original post...